How to paginate text in a Typography element?
How do I add pagination to a Typography component?
I have mocked up a DocumentTextPanel component that is currently rendering hard-coded text in a Typograpy element. I will be collecting the text to render from a backend, and that text will be much longer than a single page.
I've read the Pagination documentation as well as the Typography documentation
but I don't know how to integrate these into a paginated DocumentTextPanel. I think I want to replace the <pre>...</pre> with text collected from a prop or even collected from an enclosing context. I invite guidance about how to approach this.
Is there documentation that describes how to add a Pagination element to a Typography element?
Here is the code for my hard-coded spike:
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';

export default function DocumentTextPanel ({
}) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ padding:"0.5rem 0.75rem 0.5rem 10rem", width: "auto"}}>
      <Typography variant="body2" component="span">
        <pre>
          An Oregon judge enters the final order striking down a voter-approved gun control law<br/>
          <br/>
          Updated 7:14 PM EST, January 9, 2024<br/>
          <br/>
          PORTLAND, Ore. (AP) — An Oregon judge has entered the final order striking down a gun control law that was narrowly approved by voters in 2022.<br/>
          <br/>
          Harney County Circuit Court Judge Robert Raschio signed the general judgment on Monday. The judgment finalizes the opinion Raschio issued in November finding the law violated the right to bear arms under the Oregon Constitution.<br/>
          <br/>
          The law, one of the toughest in the nation, was among the first gun restrictions to be passed after a major U.S. Supreme Court ruling last year changed the guidance judges are expected to follow when considering Second Amendment cases.<br/>
          <br/>
          The law requires people to undergo a criminal background check and complete a gun safety training course to obtain a permit to buy a firearm. It also bans high-capacity magazines.<br/>
          <br/>
          Measure 114 has been tied up in state and federal court since it was approved by voters in November 2022.<br/>
          <br/>
          The state trial stemmed from a lawsuit filed by gun owners claiming the law violated the right to bear arms under the state constitution. Oregon Attorney General Ellen Rosenblum, one of the defendants in the case, vowed to appeal the ruling.<br/>
        </pre>
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  )
}

